# Правильный шестиугольник по 3 точкам в гексагональной системе координат

Tags: геометрия, координаты

работаю с гексагональной системой координат и появилась такая задача:

> Дано три точки. Построить правильный шестиугольник, проходящий
> через них (все три точки должны лежать НА ГРАНИЦЕ, а не ВНУТРИ,
> шестиугольника). Если шестиугольников существует более одного, выбрать
> имеющий минимальный радиус. Если шестиугольника не существует -
> вернуть null.

Моих знаний в области геометрии недостаточно, чтоб понять, как определить, где находится центр такого шестиугольника, единственная идея, которая у меня возникла, это взять область вокруг каждой точки, равную максимальному расстоянию между ними и перебрать каждую точку в области, однако это очень долго и явно существует более быстрый метод это сделать.

**Пример гексагональной системы координат:** (Первая цифра - y, вторая - x)

```
      60  61  62  63  64  65
    50  51  52  53  54  55  56
  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38
  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28
    12  13  14  15  16  17  18
      03  04  05  06  07  08
```

Пример шестиугольников:

- Через точки 13, 32 и 44 проходит правильный шестиугольник с центром в 24 и радиусом 2.
- Для точек 13, 32 и 45 такого шестиугольника не существует.
- Для точек 32, 33 и 35 следует вернуть шестиугольник радиусом 3 (с центром в 62 или 05).

Надеюсь у вас будут какие-то идеи или предложения

Comment: Берёшь уравнение прямой на гексагональной сетке, которая находится на определённом расстоянии от определённой точки. В этом уравнении три переменные - две координаты точки и расстояние. Строишь систему из трёх уравнений, для трёх данных точек, решаешь. Если получено не-целочисленное решение, то ответ отрицателен. Если получено целочисленное решение - проверяешь, что все три точки находятся внутри шестиугольника, по результату ответ или положителен, или отрицателен. Если система вырождена (как в последнем примере) - то крайние из трёх точек определяют сторону.

Comment: PS. Как я понимаю, рассматриваются только шестиугольники со сторонами параллельными осям сетки.

Comment: Да, вы правы, рассматриваются только шестиугольники, параллельные осям. Я не очень понял, что вы имеете ввиду под "уравнение прямой на гексагональной сетке, которая находится на определённом расстоянии от определённой точки", точнее я не смог найти это уравнение. Можете ли вы либо написать эту формулу, либо скинуть сайт с информацией об этом. В любом случае огромное вам спасибо

Comment: *я не смог найти это уравнение* Вообще-то Вы должны были его построить самостоятельно. Выберите точку, с координатами XY. Выберите прямую на расстоянии N от неё. Посмотрите координаты точек этой прямой. Составьте уравнение (точнее, 3 варианта такого уравнения, один из которых тривиальный).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно решить как-то с помощью одного уравнения я не смог, пришлось изобретать велосипед.

### Алгоритм:

---

Моя идея состоит в том, чтоб каждую итерацию рисовать окружность радиуса `R (R+1, R+2...)`.
Каждую такую итерацию брать все точки на границе каждой из окружностей и искать точки, которые находятся в каждой из границ.
Если несколько раз нарисовать это задание, то становится очевидно, что именно такие точки и являются центрами наших гексагональных окружностей.

***Но возникает вопрос:*** *Когда можно остановиться, перестать увеличивать радиус и вернуть null?"*
Тут все просто: Увеличиваем до тех пор, пока не достигнем максимальной дистанции (т.е. пока все центры окружностей не будут находится в каждой из окружностей). Опять же, это становится очевидно после нескольких часов рисований гексов на листике.

### Оптимизации:

---

С алгоритмом худо-бедно разобрались, теперь нужно оптимизировать, чтоб не ждать результата 20 лет.
К сожалению чего-то очень умного придумать не вышло, единственное - за начальное значение `R` явно имеет смысл брать *максимальное расстояние* между гексами, деленное на 2 (потому что только с этого значения все три окружности начинают пересекаться)

На данный момент это все оптимизации, которые были придуманы.

### Код:

---

Используется язык **kotlin** т.к. именно для этого языка мне давали задачу. Весь код можно увидеть по [ссылке](https://github.com/DafterPlay/KotlinAsFirst2021/blob/master/src/lesson8/task1/Hex.kt) (функция hexagonByThreePoints)
Из-за особенности структуры кода задания будет сложно перенести все сюда.